# Google maps not showing in html

Tags: javascript, django, html, google-maps

Apologies, I am really new to this - I am following the google tutorials however I am unable to get the map to show in the html. I know the javascript is executing as I can see some manual console logs I put through the script. I also know the location is taken from the user.

I have 2 separate files, googlemaps.js and home.html:

```
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="{% static 'js/googlemaps.js' %}"></script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA9etM9rqnYas63ypURAkvEFn_W_sU0NM4&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map">
      <style>
        #map {
          height: 400px;
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And in the js file I have :

```
var curLat = null; //user location
var curLon = null;

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
        window.alert("no location");
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    curLat = position.coords.latitude;
    curLon = position.coords.longitude;
}
function initMap(){
  getLocation() //finds out user location to fomat the map
  if (curLat == null){
    curLat = 42.3601;   //if the user location cannot be found, set default ones
    curLon = -71.0589;   // of boston
    console.log("random locations");
  }
  var options = {
    zoom:10,
    center:{lat:curLat, lng:curLon}
  }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),options);
}
```

If possible, could you please point me to what I am doing wrong in the HTML? Thank you

Comment: Use just `<script src="js/googlemaps.js"></script>`

Comment: @YadhuBabu Thank you for the suggestion however the {% static 'js/googlemaps.js' %} is a django syntax. Using only <script src="js/googlemaps.js"></script>  will not find the relevant file. Also, as the question states,  I know the javascript is executing as I can see some manual console logs I put through the script. It is therefore not the js issue but the html issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two errors:

1- You have to use if(curLat == null) note that double equal
2- The style property for map is not set correctly.

This two files in same folder work for me:

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Title</title>
<script src="googlemaps.js"></script>

</head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA9etM9rqnYas63ypURAkvEFn_W_sU0NM4&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And googlemaps.js:

```
var curLat = null; //user location
var curLon = null;

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
        window.alert("no location");
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    curLat = position.coords.latitude;
    curLon = position.coords.longitude;
}
function initMap(){
  getLocation() //finds out user location to fomat the map
  if (curLat == null){
    curLat = 42.3601;   //if the user location cannot be found, set default ones
    curLon = -71.0589;   // of boston
    console.log("random locations");
  }
  var options = {
    zoom:10,
    center:{lat:curLat, lng:curLon}
  }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),options);
}
```

Regards.

Comment: This worked, Thank you so much! Have a lovely day :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a few things wrong, firstly you are using  which is usually used for templating systems such as twig. To include your js file all you need is

After that where it says if(curLat = null) you are setting the variable to null. I would use if(curLat == null || curLon == null)

Comment: Hi Tom, Thank you for your answer - Well spotted about the == I did not see that! Also, the js file executes fine as I can see by the console log I just can't see the map in the HTML....

Comment: Forgot to mention, you need to move the style out of the div and put it in the header.